# Having force close error with open new intent for Google Map

Tags: java, android, string, google-maps, floating-point

I'm getting the lat and lng from one URL.
In my coding,
it will be like,
if(lat==1.3005060 && lng== 103.8745850) ,
it will open up up the next class, map.java.
else, invalid map.

I've initially declare it as string to display it as text view.
Next I've declare it as float in the onClick method,
so that it can pass to google map.
However,
there is force close error occuring.
Can someone guide me?

LogCat Error:

```
08-14 11:07:13.190: E/AndroidRuntime(457): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-14 11:07:13.190: E/AndroidRuntime(457): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
08-14 11:07:13.190: E/AndroidRuntime(457):  at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2185)
08-14 11:07:13.190: E/AndroidRuntime(457):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2585)
08-14 11:07:13.190: E/AndroidRuntime(457):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9299)
08-14 11:07:13.190: E/AndroidRuntime(457):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
08-14 11:07:13.190: E/AndroidRuntime(457):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
08-14 11:07:13.190: E/AndroidRuntime(457):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
08-14 11:07:13.190: E/AndroidRuntime(457):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3691)
08-14 11:07:13.190: E/AndroidRuntime(457):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-14 11:07:13.190: E/AndroidRuntime(457):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
08-14 11:07:13.190: E/AndroidRuntime(457):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:912)
08-14 11:07:13.190: E/AndroidRuntime(457):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:670)
08-14 11:07:13.190: E/AndroidRuntime(457):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-14 11:07:13.190: E/AndroidRuntime(457): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
08-14 11:07:13.190: E/AndroidRuntime(457):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-14 11:07:13.190: E/AndroidRuntime(457):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
08-14 11:07:13.190: E/AndroidRuntime(457):  at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2180)
08-14 11:07:13.190: E/AndroidRuntime(457):  ... 11 more
08-14 11:07:13.190: E/AndroidRuntime(457): Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: latitude
08-14 11:07:13.190: E/AndroidRuntime(457):  at org.apache.harmony.luni.util.FloatingPointParser.initialParse(FloatingPointParser.java:114)
08-14 11:07:13.190: E/AndroidRuntime(457):  at org.apache.harmony.luni.util.FloatingPointParser.parseFloat(FloatingPointParser.java:319)
08-14 11:07:13.190: E/AndroidRuntime(457):  at java.lang.Float.parseFloat(Float.java:323)
08-14 11:07:13.190: E/AndroidRuntime(457):  at com.example.fambond.SingleMenuItemActivity.onClick(SingleMenuItemActivity.java:75)
08-14 11:07:13.190: E/AndroidRuntime(457):  ... 14 more
```

part of my code for singlemenu.java

```
public void onClick(View v) {
         //TODO Auto-generated method stub
    float lat=Float.parseFloat(KEY_LATITUDE);
    float lng =Float.parseFloat(KEY_LONGITUDE);
    if(lat==1.3005060 && lng== 103.8745850){ 
    Log.d("coords", "lat: " + KEY_LATITUDE + " long: " + KEY_LONGITUDE);
    Intent intent = new Intent(SingleMenuItemActivity.this,map.class);
    intent.putExtra("MAP",KEY_LATITUDE.toString());
    intent.putExtra("MAP",KEY_LONGITUDE.toString());
    startActivity(intent);

    }
    else
    {
        Toast.makeText(SingleMenuItemActivity.this, "Invalid MAP", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Which is line 75 in `SingleMenuItemActivity.java` ? Also which data type is `KEY_LATITUDE` variable ?

Comment: line 75 is float lat=Float.parseFloat(KEY_LATITUDE);
Key_latitude, I declare it as string, but in the website it is signed float. 
i'm able to retrieve it as textview for lat and lng, but couldnt pass it into google map

Comment: If `KEY_LATITUDE` is string containing the float value like `KEY_LATITUDE` = "1.3005060" then parsing should be okay. But iuf is a string then why are you using `KEY_LATITUDE.toString()` etc?

Comment: then, how should I convert it instead?
initially, it is declare at string

Comment: Err, in your other question you have `static final float KEY_LATITUDE = "latitude";` and `static final float KEY_LONGITUDE = "longitude";`. Which is totally wrong.

Comment: so, I shouldn't put them in?

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be that you are comparing floats with `==` sign. The correct way to test floats for 'equality' is:

```
if( (Math.abs(lat-1.3005060) < epsilon) && (Math.abs(lng-103.8745850) < epsilon) ){
}
```

where epsilon is a very small number like 0.00000001, depending on the desired precision.

See [What's wrong with using == to compare floats in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1088216/whats-wrong-with-using-to-compare-floats-in-java) and [Manipulating and comparing floating points in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2896013/manipulating-and-comparing-floating-points-in-java) question for more.

Comment: I've to decalre epsolon?

Comment: Yes. either you can declare it or use it in place of the variable. Like: 
`Math.abs(lat-1.3005060)<0.00001)`.

Comment: can you help me with this?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18222983/declaring-float-value-get-float-value