# Declaring float value, get float value

Tags: java, android, string, floating-point

I would like to ask
If I've problem trying to change my code for lat and lng into float,
 can anyone guide me with it.
previously, it is in string, but now i would like to decalre it as float.
I've done some, but I not sure if it is correctly done.

```
 public class AndroidXMLParsingActivity extends ListActivity {
        static final String KEY = "weatherFilter";
        String URL = "";

        // XML node keys
        static final String KEY_EVENT = "event"; // parent node
        static final String KEY_TITLE = "title";
        static final String KEY_URL = "url";
        static final String KEY_DESC = "description";
        static final String KEY_START_TIME = "start_time";
        static final String KEY_STOP_TIME = "stop_time";
        static final String KEY_VENUE_NAME = "venue_name";
        static final String KEY_COUNTRY_NAME = "country_name";
        static final String KEY_VENUE_ADDRESS = "venue_address";
        static final String KEY_VENUE = "venue";
        static final float KEY_LATITUDE = "latitude";
        static final float KEY_LONGITUDE = "longitude";
            public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Intent in = getIntent();
        URL = in.getStringExtra(KEY);
        final ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> menuItems = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();
        String xml = parser.getXmlFromUrl(URL); // getting XML
        Document doc = parser.getDomElement(xml); // getting DOM element

        NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_EVENT);
        // looping through all item nodes <item>
        for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
            // creating new HashMap
            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
            Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);
            // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
            map.put(KEY_TITLE, parser.getValue(e, KEY_TITLE));
            map.put(KEY_URL, parser.getValue(e, KEY_URL));
            map.put(KEY_DESC, "Description: " + parser.getValue(e, KEY_DESC));
            map.put(KEY_START_TIME, parser.getValue(e, KEY_START_TIME));
            map.put(KEY_STOP_TIME, parser.getValue(e, KEY_STOP_TIME));
            map.put(KEY_VENUE_NAME, parser.getValue(e, KEY_VENUE_NAME));
            map.put(KEY_COUNTRY_NAME, parser.getValue(e, KEY_COUNTRY_NAME));
            map.put(KEY_VENUE_ADDRESS, parser.getValue(e, KEY_VENUE_ADDRESS));

            float lat=Float.parseFloat(KEY_LATITUDE);
                   float lng=Float.parseFloat(KEY_LONGITUDE);
            map.put(KEY_VENUE, parser.getValue(e, KEY_VENUE_NAME) + ", " + parser.getValue(e, KEY_VENUE_ADDRESS));

            // adding HashList to ArrayList

            menuItems.add(map);


        }



        // Adding menuItems to ListView
        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, menuItems,
                R.layout.list_item, new String[] { KEY_TITLE, KEY_DESC,  KEY_COUNTRY_NAME,
                        KEY_VENUE , KEY_LATITUDE,KEY_LONGITUDE, KEY_START_TIME, }, new int[] {
                        R.id.title, R.id.description, R.id.countryName, R.id.venueName, R.id.lat,R.id.lng,
                        R.id.startTime });

        setListAdapter(adapter);

        // selecting single ListView item
        ListView lv = getListView();

        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                // getting values from selected ListItem
                String title = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title))
                        .getText().toString();
                String description = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.description))
                        .getText().toString();
                String venue = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.venueName))
                        .getText().toString();
                String lat = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.lat))
                        .getText().toString();

                String lng = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.lng  ))
                        .getText().toString();

                // Starting new intent
                Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        SingleMenuItemActivity.class);
                in.putExtra(KEY_TITLE, title);
                in.putExtra(KEY_DESC, description);
                in.putExtra(KEY_VENUE, venue);
                in.putExtra(KEY_LATITUDE, lat);
                in.putExtra(KEY_LONGITUDE, lng);
                startActivity(in);

            }
        });



    }
}
```

Comment: If you're just trying to make a String into a float, you can use `Float.parseFloat(myString)`. Otherwise, I don't understand your question

Comment: in my code,initially, i've declare  it as string, now i would like to change to float, how do I do it? I not sure if I've done the right way

Comment: @randomize :  I believe this is not a question to be asked here at SO. You need to learn JAVA first. Please use Google for this simple casting things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be quite confused. You need to parse the values into floats *from the XML parser*. Change this:

```
float lat=Float.parseFloat(KEY_LATITUDE);
float lng=Float.parseFloat(KEY_LONGITUDE);
```

To:

```
float lat=Float.parseFloat(parser.getValue(KEY_LATITUDE));
float lng=Float.parseFloat(parser.getValue(KEY_LONGITUDE));
```

Otherwise you're just parsing "longitude" and "latitude" into floats which obviously won't work.

Comment: in my XML parser,
do I have to write anything?

Comment: public String getValue(float keyLatitude) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  return null;
 }

Comment: Presumably the parser just returns a string?

Answer (score 1):

Since you've cluttered your problem with all of your code it's not easy to identify all of the problems with your code, however this seems obvious:

You will need to replace

```
float lat=Float.parseFloat(KEY_LATITUDE);
```

with

```
float lat=Float.parseFloat((String) map.get(KEY_LATITUDE));
```

Comment: is this correct?
 in.putExtra(KEY_LATITUDE, lat);
                in.putExtra(KEY_LONGITUDE, lng);

Comment: why at  static final float KEY_LONGITUDE = "longitude"; it underline the "longitude" and ask if I would like to change to string when I mouse over, why is it so?

Comment: you are beyond help via SO.